# How to display multilingual resource text at design time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I'm working on a WPF-application which shall be multilingual.
So i followed the steps in this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123460/Simplest-Way-to-Implement-Multilingual-WPF-Applica) and added some resource dictionaries to my project.
Then i add one of these dictionarioes to the window by the following method, which i'm calling - for test purposes - in the constructor of the window:

```
    private void SetLanguageDictionary()
    {
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();

        switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
        {
            case "en-US":
            case "en-GB":
                dict.Source = new Uri("Resources\\StringResources_en-US.xaml",
                              UriKind.Relative);
                break;
            case "de-DE":
                dict.Source = new Uri("Resources\\StringResources_de-DE.xaml",
                                  UriKind.Relative);
                break;
            default:
                dict.Source = new Uri("Resources\\StringResources_de-DE.xaml",
                                  UriKind.Relative);
                break;
        }

        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
    }
```

Finally i implemented the resources in the labels on my window like that:

```
    <Label Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Margin="5"
           Content="{DynamicResource firstname}"></Label>
```

If the current culture on my PC is "en-US" the content will be "First name".
Or in case of "de-DE" (german) "Vorname".

At runtime it works fine, but at designtime i can't see the texts.

What have i to do?

Comment: I think you might be doing it the hard way,  I use Content="{Binding CommonDate, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"   where Resources is Resources.resx

Comment: This sounds like a job for dependency injection.  I use the MVVM Light toolkit from NuGet - by default, the data you bind to will come from one of two dataservices (repositories) - you have a design dataservice, which handles dummy data for design, and your production dataservice, which is used at runtime.  In your viewmodel, you retrieve the objects that you are binding to from the dataservice, but you will get different objects depending on which dataservice is being used (which in turn depends on whether you are in design mode.)  You can find more info at https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it out.

I had to implement the ResourceDictionary in Window.Resources.
To do that, some tags have to be added ("ResourceDictionary", "ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries").

If there are styles defined they have to be moved inside the tag "ResourceDictionary" as You can see below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StringResources_en-US.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="style1">
            [...]
        </Style>

        [...]
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then You can see the texts from the xaml-file in the controls which are bound to it as dynamic resource.
And because it is used as dynamic resource, it can be overwritten in code-behind:

```
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        dict.Source = new Uri("Resources\\StringResources_de-DE.xaml",
                                  UriKind.Relative);
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```